# Remove default padding from List in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

When using ScrollView the views inside it are spread across the whole screen width by default, but when using List, there is a padding on the sides. Is there a way to get rid of this padding?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To achieve this you need to use `ForEach` inside `List` combined with `.listRowInsets` as in example below

[image: demo]

```
struct Demo: View {
    var colors: [Color] = [.red, .blue, .yellow]
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(colors, id: \.self) { color in
                color
            }.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
        }
        // Update: Different iOS versions have different 
        // default List styles, so set explicit one if needed
        .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For **iOS 15.0+**, you may try `listStyle` modifier and set it as `plain`.

```swift
var body: some View {
        List {
            // some rows
        }
        .listStyle(.plain)
    }
```