# How to remove the leading and trailing space space in the cell SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am a beginner in SwiftUI and i am stuck on this.

I want to remove the leading and trailing white space in cell as in the picture [Sample output Picture][1]

That is the orange color should touch the left and right margin of the iPhone screen
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhiFR.png

Here is my code  -
{

```
var body : some View {
    
    List(0 ..< 15) { item in
        
        VStack() {
            
            HStack{
                VStack(alignment: .leading){
                    Text("sample text is t iu ")
                        .fontWeight(.medium)
                    Text("Sample text 2 jksbdkj")
                    
                }
                Spacer()
                
                Image("pro1")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame( height: 50)
                
                
            }
            // bottom view of card
            HStack(){
                Image("pro2")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                Text("0")
                Text("+3")
                
                Spacer()
                
                Image(systemName: "pencil")
                Image("pro3")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
            }
            
        }
            .background(Color.orange)
            .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
            
    }
    .listStyle(.plain)
    .background(Color.green)
    
    
}
```

}

I appreciate any help . Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/60910124/12299030?

Comment: @Asperi Yes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i am a beginner in SwiftUI and learning my self.

How to change the color between the two cell in a list in SwiftUI [Sample picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8omg4.png)

I want the white colors to be grey.

Here is my code -

```
struct cardView: View{

    var body : some View {
        List(0 ..< 15) { item in
            
            VStack() {
                
                HStack{
                    VStack(alignment: .leading){
                        Text("sample text is t iu ")
                            .fontWeight(.medium)
                        Text("Sample text 2 jksbdkj")
                        
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Image("pro1")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame( height: 50)
                    
                    
                }
                // bottom view of card
                HStack(){
                    Image("pro2")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                    Text("0")
                    Text("+3")
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Image(systemName: "pencil")
                    Image("pro3")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                }
                
            }    .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
                .background(Color.orange)
                .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                Spacer()
        }
        .listStyle(.plain)
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
        cardView()
        }.background(Color.black)
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any help thanks.