# How to change a Hstack color in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a little problem with a Hstack. The HStack is located in a List, but when I tried to change the color, I have this behaviour: **Photo** - > [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIre3.png)

It looks like that is only put the color next to the text.

How can I solve this issue?

I'll post the code below:

```
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(Texts.cartViewText5)
                .font(.system(size: 20))
                .bold()
            
                .padding(.leading, 30)
            List {
                ForEach(coreDataViewModel.savedCartToShow) { car in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        HStack {
                            WebImage(url: car.imageUrl, options: .refreshCached)
                              .onFailure(perform: { (error) in
                              } )
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFit()
                                .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                                .padding()
                            
                            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                                Text(car.name ?? "")
                                    .font(.system(size: 16))
                                    .foregroundColor(.blackWhite)
                                
                                
                                
                                HStack {
                                    Text("\(car.price) lei")
                                        .foregroundColor(.colorGrayDark)
                                    
                                    Text("\(car.grams , specifier: "%.0f") g ")
                                        .font(.system(size: 16))
                                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                }
                            }
                            Spacer()
                            Button {
                                deleteTest(car)
                            } label: {
                                Image(systemName: "minus.circle")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .foregroundColor(.tabItemColor)
                                    .frame(width: 26, height: 26)
                            }
                            Text("x\(coreDataViewModel.countDictionary[car.id] ?? 0)")
                                .font(.headline)
                            
                            Button {
                                addTest(car)
                            } label:  {
                                Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .foregroundColor(.turqoise)
                                    .frame(width: 26, height: 26)
                            }
                                
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
                .listRowBackground(Color.backgroundLightDark)
                HStack {
                    Text("Total : ")
                    Spacer()
                    Text("\(coreDataViewModel.savedMenu.map{$0.price}.reduce(0, +)) lei")
                        .foregroundColor(.orange)
                }
                .background(Color.backgroundLightDark)
            }
     
            .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
            
        }
```

Comment: are you referring to the `HStack` with the `Text("Total : ")` in it? If so it seems to work for me, changed to `.background(Color.blue)` and it shows blue.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/60910124/12299030? Or this https://stackoverflow.com/a/62598818/12299030?

Answer (score 0):

In SwiftUI, when you apply the .background modifier to a view, it only applies the background color to the view's content, not the entire view itself. To change the background color of the entire HStack, you can wrap it inside another view and apply the background color to that wrapper view.

```
   ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.blue)
            HStack {
                Text("Total: ")
                Spacer()
                Text("car")
                    .foregroundColor(.orange)
            }
            .padding()
        }
```