# List padding issue - elements have weird left margin

Tags: swift, swiftui

Experiencing a weird issue with my list. Looking at the screenshot provided below, my sub titles under "Eggs" all have a left margin issue, which pushes the sub headers away from there starting position. I don't think it's my padding causing this, honestly stumped, hoping you guys could help out.
Thanks!

[image]

```
struct FoodSearchResultsView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var foodApi: FoodApiSearch
    @EnvironmentObject var mealEntryObj: MealEntrys
    
    //textfield input
    @State private var searchResultsItem = ""
    //if toggled, will display, binded to search bar
    @Binding var userSearch: Bool
    
    //when false, api results will not display
    @Binding var isViewSearching:Bool //sending to searchboar
    
    var body: some View {
        if userSearch{
            VStack{
                Text(isViewSearching ? "Results" : "Searching..")
                Spacer()
              //  delays showing api call
                    .onAppear {
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.7) {
                            self.isViewSearching = true
                               }
                           }
                //if user has completed searching for a food
                if isViewSearching{
                    List(foodApi.userSearchResults){meal in
                        VStack{
                            HStack{
                                VStack(alignment: .leading){
                                    Text(meal.mealName)
                                        .padding(.leading,-50)
                                    HStack{
                                        Text(meal.calories + "cals, ")
                                            .font(.caption)
                                            .offset(y:8)
                                        Text(meal.brand)
                                            .font(.caption)
                                            .offset(y:8)
                                        }
                                    .frame(maxWidth:150)
                                    .padding(.leading,-50)
                                   
                                    }
                                 .foregroundColor(.black)
                                //Spacer()
                                Button(action: {
                                    userSearch = false
                                    isViewSearching = false //is user actively searching, communicates with journalEntryMain
                                    //push meal to meal entry break fast
                                    mealEntryObj.mealEntrysBreakfast.append(meal)
                                }){
                                    Image(systemName: "plus.app")
                                        .font(.title2)
                                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                                        .offset(x: 70)
                                        .frame(width:50)
                                }
                               
                            }
                        }
                        .frame(width:220, height:40) //width of background
                        .padding([.leading, .trailing], 60)
                        .padding([.top, .bottom], 10)
                        .background(RoundedRectangle(
                            cornerRadius:20).fill(Color("LightWhite")))
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                            
                        }
                    .listStyle(.plain)
                    .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                    //.frame(height:400)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you need to add more `alignment` properties to make sure the frames/stacks are aligned to `leading` -- you do this once, but not on the outer stacks. Unfortunately, no one can run your code to test/alter it, since it relies on a bunch of missing types. If you include a [mre], someone can likely provide an exact solution for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/60910124/12299030?